# how to fixed the footer when content is aligned vertically

Tags: css, html

I have a very not typical site where content is aligned by the middle of screen I mean vertically and horizontally, for getting this result used `vertical-align: middle;` for each item and for the main container 
`text-align: center; height: calc(100% - header - footer ))`

[image]

but when the user is changing size

for the window the footer is also change his position but should not do it
[image]

Js fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/hm97o1sa/

is there any way to fix it without "flex" ?

updated:
expected behavior

scrolled to the top 
[image]

scrolled to the bottom
[image]

Comment: You've calculated the content height in percentage. But, individual items are fixed in pixels. Make those fluid as well.

Comment: Quick fix would be adding `overflow-y: scroll;` on content panel in the middle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution would be to use `calc` together with Viewport units `vh`.

With `calc()`, you can perform calculations to determine CSS property values.

With Viewport units, you can get work with Viewport size, for example in this case 100% of the Viewport height (`vh`).

```css
    html,
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    #header {
      height: 100px;
      background: blue;
    }
    
    #content {
      height: calc(100vh - 150px);
      min-height: 250px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    #vert-align {
      display: inline-block;
      height: 100%;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    
    #item_1 {
      background: yellow;
      height: 250px;
      width: 250px;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      margin-right: 50px;
    }
    
    #item_2 {
      background: red;
      height: 250px;
      width: 250px;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    
    #footer {
      height: 50px;
      background: green;
    }
```

```html
<div id="header">HEADER</div>
<div id="content">
  <div id="vert-align"></div>
  <div id="item_1"></div>
  <div id="item_2"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer">FOOTER</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your CSS and your Final code will be:

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
#header {
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
}
#content {
   height: calc(100% - 150px);
   text-align: center;
   overflow-y: auto;
}
#vert-align {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#item_1 {
    background: yellow;
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
#item_2 {
    background: red;
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#footer {
    height: 50px;
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TA</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header">HEADER</div>
    <div id="content">
      <div id="vert-align"></div>
      <div id="item_1"></div>
      <div id="item_2"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">FOOTER</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your help :) 
but the client doesn't want to have such scroll bar :(
I'm thinking maybe I have to do it with js

Comment: then what is the requirement..?? what should be the response when the height decreases?

Comment: Updated the post, with expected behavior

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix is to apply a `min-height: 250px` on your `#content`

```
#content {
    height: calc(100% - 150px);
    min-height: 250px;
    text-align: center;
}
```